# Air to IPad Release Build failing on asset loads

Tags: ios, air, flash-builder

Having some issues getting a release build of an Air IOS Ipad app running (starling based).

I am doing a release build, and saving the ipa file on my drive.  I double click the ipa to get it into iTunes, and from there I do an app install onto the iPad.

Once on the ipad, the app fails to load any external files.
I put up a preloader, and attempt to load assets via Loadermax, however, it seems to fail.

Here is the code section that the app fails on: (NOTE: this all works in debug mode, both in Air simulator, and debug mode on device via usb)

```
import com.greensock.events.LoaderEvent;
import com.greensock.loading.ImageLoader;
import flash.filesystem.File;
 ...
 ...
var _imageLoader:ImageLoader;
 ...
 ...
private function loadAssets():void{
  var _appFile:File = File.applicationDirectory;
  _appFile = _appFile.resolvePath("assets/statics/blueImage.png");
  _imageLoader = new ImageLoader(_appFile.nativePath, {onComplete:onImageLoaded, onFail:onImageLoadFail});
}
private function onImageLoaded(e:LoaderEvent):void{
  traceOut("OH MY GOD BATMAN, IT WORKED!!!");   // traceOut is a helper method that prints to a textfield on the display
}
private function onImageLoadFail(e:LoaderEvent):void{
  traceOut("back to the Bat Cave...");
}
...
...
```

In debug mode, the above code shows:

```
OH MY GOD BATMAN, IT WORKED!!!
```

In release build:

```
back to the Bat Cave...
```

Anyone know where I am going off the rails?  I am not using any ANE's or such.
Based in SDK: "http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/14.0"

Comment: Are you specifying the external files to be included in the exported IPA?

Comment: Using flash builder, I am specifying the files to be included (folders)....

Comment: Does it work when using Standard Debug mode or just Fast Debug mode? My guess is you are good in Fast, which is actually just a Flash app, but not okay in Standard, which is a cross-compiled Objective-C app that does not run in the Flash runtime. This would explain why it works in debug and not in release (which is close to Standard Debug). I generally access embedded files using the `[Embed()]` syntax or, if using Flex, the `Embed()` syntax.

Comment: The app uses way too many assets for me to embed them all on compile, so I gotta do a loader.  I am doing a "Standard" debugging on device.

Comment: I took a second look at the project build packaging options and I do see the "assets" and "configuration" folders and subcontaining files all checked, however, when I choose to do a release build, I don't see those folders as options to check/uncheck ---- do you think that's where things are going off the rails?  Or can I assume that since they are selected via the "project build packaging" options, they are already included?

Comment: those folder should be available for check/uncheck when creating a release build. If they are not try to refresh the project then run a clean command. As long as those folders can't be included in the package nothing will work. Remember also you can check the contents of your apk/ipa since those are mainly zip files. Unzip them and check what's really inside in debug and release mode.

Comment: I took a look at the ipa file, with winRar, and I see that the "assets" folder and "configuration" folder are not included.

so, I tried to add the files to the package via the "customize launch" button and "Add Files to Package" on the subsequent window.
but, when I try to create the build via the "Finish" button, I get an error that states:  
"G:\Repositiories\Test\bin-debug\assets (Access is denied)"

Comment: anyway that I can manually add the folders to the build?

Comment: I've got exactly the same issue but its NOT caused because of missing assets. I've got all my assets in my .ipa (I'm using IntelliJ). Anyone else experienced this?

Comment: @SudoPlz :  After running around with this problem a few times, I can make a few suggestions that might be the issue

1.  Check your release build and make sure all the files you need are in the ipa for deploy

2.  Check the casing on your files, MAC be perilous

3.  Check your run with Adobe Scout to see where things go sour.

Comment: @SudoPlz :  After running around with this problem a few times, I can make a few suggestions that might help track the issue down:

1.  Check your release build and make sure all the files you need are in the ipa for deploy

2.  Check the casing on your files, MAC is the most annnnnnnoying....

3.  Check your run with Adobe Scout to see where things go sour.

4.  USE AN OVERLAY DEBUGGER!!  Since you can't trace, put in a debugging window/overlay, to trace out the threads.

Comment: @SudoPlz:  Also note BotMaster's comment in relation to suggestion (2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, Thank you to to the individuals who assisted in getting to the root of this problem and solving, especially BotMaster.

The issue really has to do with Flashbuilder, and a bug that is associated with it's Build Release wizard.

After reading this:
https://forums.adobe.com/message/5750011

What I did was:

1. click the "Export Release Build" button in Flashbuilder,
2. IMPORTANT:  check the box for "Keep bin-release-temp folder"
3. Click Next
4. Click Cancel
5. Via Windows Explorer, navigated to the bin-debug folder, and copied the "assets" and "configuration" folders to the "bin-debug-temp" folder that was generated by flash-builder
6. I return to Flash builder, and Click on "Export Release Build" button again.
7. Check the box for "Keep bin-release-temp folder"
8. Click Next
9. Check the boxes beside "assets" and "configuration", Click Finish.

the newly generated ipa file had the folders I required.

Once again, thanks to those who contributed to resolve this bug.

Answer (score 1):

PCs are not case sensitive but Ios is. While in simulator or debug mode a file name "myFile" would work even if it's really "myfile" (note the cap difference) on release mode it will fail.

If that doesn't work then try using the url property of File instead of nativePath. Also you can easily check is the file exist prior to loading it:

```
if(_appFile.exist)
```

Also when depending on custom frameworks you force yourself on depending on their shortcomings. Use a classic Loader instance to repeat the same operation and see if that one succeed. You'll be surprise the number of times a custom framework can fail on simple operations simply because the way it's setup internally.

Comment: Hmmmm... Didn't think of that, gonna give it a go and see if that works. Fingers crossed (will tell you monday).

Comment: I have commented out the core of the application and have brought it to a point where all it's doing is starting up starling, and, load in a sharedobject (which seems to work, as it reaches the success handler for it), and then I attempt to load in an xml file via a urlloader:

var _appFile:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("configuion/config.xml");
_urlLoader.load(new URLRequest(_appFile.nativePath));  

gives back an IO error... (path must be incorrect, or files not there)... how can I check what files got installed (explore the ipa)??

Comment: a urlloader is gonna want the url property of File not the nativepath. keep nativepath for file operations only.

Comment: so what should the code there be?  

new URLRequest("configuration/config.xml") ?

doesn't the native path just translate to a string like: 
"\var\somestuff\GUID\myApp\configuration\config.xml"  ?  shouldn't that work?

It flies in debug...

Comment: nativepath will give you a path that only the system can read while url will give you a url (universal type of link). URLLoader can't read a nativepath link, only the File system package can. URLLoader can read a url. _appFile.url would be correct for a URLLoader. For example on PCs a nativepath will use \ instead of / for all links.